Conversation with a Word
Who are you?

Somewhat.

Someone?

Someone can be I. Or not.

Can't you be plain with me?

You're opposing me.

That's not fair!

I am, though.

Are you?

Reasonably.

To a degree, then?

Not quite.

I see.

Do you?
Hint:

 Think synonyms


Someone can be I - can be a person;
You’re opposing me - I am on the opposite side of the word;
Maybe reflection?

This is not what I was thinking about, but good guess! I've added a hint.
